# .htaccess rewrite with multiple parameters

Tags: .htaccess

I had a rule in my `.htaccess` that makes URLs for articles more friendly looking for the purposes of SEO and the like.

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule ^(news-and-views)/(.+).php /$1/article.php?title=$2 [L]
```

Which converted this URL:

`/news-and-views/going-for-brokering.php`

To this within the application itself:

`/news-and-views/article.php?title=going-for-brokering`

Now I need a URL with an ID before the title like this:

`/news-and-views/123456789/going-for-brokering.php`

So I tried the following rule:

`RewriteRule ^(news-and-views)/(.+)/(.+).php /$1/article.php?Id=$2&title=$3 [L]`

However, this isn't working, am I misunderstanding the use of the brackets as I thought everything between them was acknowledged as a variable on the right-hand side?

I'm thinking it could even be that the less specific rule is above the more specific rule.

Comment: .htaccess rules never make your URLs "friendly looking" – they act the other way around and resolve "speaking" URLs into a machine readable counterpart.

Comment: Excuse my backward logic.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to be careful about the order of the rules, since your first rule will also match `/news-and-views/123456789/going-for-brokering.php`. Change your rules as follows:

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule ^(news-and-views)/([^/]+).php /$1/article.php?title=$2 [L]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule ^(news-and-views)/([0-9]+)/([^/]+).php /$1/article.php?Id=$2&title=$3 [L]
```

Comment: …or reverse the order of the original rules, as stated in your text (“be careful about the order of the rules”).

Comment: Yes, but generally it's better to write more specific rules than just rely on the `L` flag.